# Changing regexes to target image links

Tags: regex

I need to batch change a folder full of files, changing all image links to lower case and replacing underscores with dashes. Thus, `<img src="/images/Maps/South_America.png">` would become `<img src="images/maps/south-america.png">`

I already performed similar operations on all local links in the same files. I used this regex to change them to lower case:

```
(?<=(?i)href=")((?:<\?php(?:(?!\?>).)+\?>)?)((?:'[^']+')?)([^"]+)(?=")

\1\2\L\3
```

And I used this one to replace underscores with dashes:

```
(href="(?!http)[^_"]+)\_([^"]+")

$1-$2
```

I'm not even sure if they're the same "language;" I think one only works in Dreamweaver, the other in TextWrangler. Anyway, I haven't figured out how to modify to match images, rather than links. I should emphasize that I only to change the image paths and names, not any classes, ID's or alt tags.

For example, `<img src="Buffalo_Bill.jpg" alt="Buffalo Bill" class="People">` would become `<img src="buffalo-bill.jpg" alt="Buffalo Bill" class="People">`

Also, I think this covers all the bases if defining image extensions is necessary...

```
(?:jpe?g|gif|png|svg|swf)
```

The regexes I posted above are just examples. If you have a regex that's totally different, that's fine - just as long as it will work in a common text editor like Dreamweaver or TextWrangler. (I'm on a Mac.)

Comment: Can you fix your images or paste a "from" to "to" example in text?

Comment: Sorry about that; I think someone fixed them for me. ;)

Comment: So you are trying to take your second regex that matches/replaces file names to only affect images?

Comment: Yes, I've already converted all my links to lower case and replaced underscores with dashes. Now I want to do the same thing with my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an input like this:

```
<img id="BoringSnowDay" class="FunkySmellsFromGarden" src="/images/Maps/South_America.png" alt="Powerball Winner!" /> <img id="ExcitingSunNight" class="SmoothTasteInKitchen" src="/images/Flags/Antartica.jpg" alt="Racecar racecaR!" />
```

This regex in TextWrangler:

```
(<img [^>]+)(src="[^"]+")
```

Replace:

```
\1\L\2
```

Gives me something that ONLY affects the `src="..."` portion and nothing else.

Unfortunately, combining that to a "...and replace `_` to `-`" tends to get a little tricky.

Comment: Yes, I'll probably need two separate regexes to do the job, as with the URL changes.

Comment: I've not seen any good pcre regex that lets you replace characters within a small area (like between `src="..."` tags), but if you want to run this multiple times: `(?<=src=")([^"]+)_([^"]+)(?=")` and replace with this: `\L\1-\L\2`, it can both lower the case and replace your underscores with dashes.

Comment: Awesome; the first one didn't work at all, but the second one nailed it. ;)